# How do I place a template variable within a template tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like the form to submit not to the `request.user`, but the `{{views.kwargs.username}}`.
I currently have the form action like so:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="{% url 'profile:make_request' username=request.user %}">
```

This is a form belonging on user-b's page, filled out by user-a, and submitted to user-b.
For `username`, I'd like to put in `{{view.kwargs.username}}`, but it does not work.

What's the proper way of passing this into the action?

Comment: you don't have to use `request.user` use `user`

Comment: @mohammedqudah the `user` and `request.user` in this context are the same. It is the logged in user. I'm trying to put the `{{views.kwargs.username}}` user into the action. That user is a different user--the one to whom the form belongs.   
edit: but youre right, I can just use either `user` or `request.user`, since they are the same.

Comment: `request.user` is a template variable in *exactly the same way* as `view.kwargs.username`. Why do you think you need to treat these differently?

Comment: You're correct. Not sure why I was having the problems I was having. May have been adding an 's' somewhere it didn't belong.